# c pointers segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

CASE 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a = 5,*p;
 *p = &a;
  printf("%d",*p);
 }
```

the above mentioned program gives the segmentation fault problem. but in the case 2 it works fine.
CASE 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a = 5,*p = &a;
printf("%d",*p);
}
```

can anyone please explain this problem. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, any beginner C language tutorial could explain the problem. Search, read; horrible dictu, think. (This is **trivial.**)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a beginners' tutorial site.

Comment: the type of `p` is `int *`. You assign `p` in case 1, not `*p`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*p = &a;
```

Dereferences `p` and assigns `&a` to the memory location `p` **is pointing to**. The pointer is uninitialized, so dereferencing it yields **undefined behavior** (thus the segmentation fault).

```
int a = 5,*p = &a;
```

Defines `a` and `p`, where the asterisk doesn't indicate dereferencing but distinguishes a usual `int` definition from a `int*` pointer definition. The line is equivalent to

```
int a = 5;
int* p = &a;
```